# How to get Elasticsearch result same as kibana or postman like other rest client in NEST term aggregate query c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elasticsearch, nest

kibana dev-tool

```
GET gltrans/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "code": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "code.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
       "total":  {
          "sum": {
             "field": "tot"
          }
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

return

```
 "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "0220",
          "doc_count" : 30182,
          "total" : {
            "value" : 169779.83551708516
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "3000",
          "doc_count" : 20360,
          "total" : {
            "value" : -477618.27972452715
          }
        },................
```

nest query

```
var result = _connectionToEs.EsClient().Search<gltrans>(s => s.Size(0)
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("code", st => st
            .Field(o => o.code.Suffix("keyword"))
            .Size(10)
            .Aggregations(aa => aa
                .Sum("total", m => m
                    .Field(o => o.tot))))));
```

return without "key" how to get key?

```
 "Items": [
        {
          "tot": {
            "Value": 169779.83551708516,
            "ValueAsString": null,
            "Meta": null
          }
        },
        {
          "tot": {
            "Value": -477618.27972452715,
            "ValueAsString": null,
            "Meta": null
          }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the key from the response

```cs
var result = _connectionToEs.EsClient().Search<gltrans>(s => s.Size(0)
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("code", st => st
            .Field(o => o.code.Suffix("keyword"))
            .Size(10)
            .Aggregations(aa => aa
                .Sum("total", m => m
                    .Field(o => o.tot))))));

var termsAgg = result.Aggregations.Terms("code");

foreach(var bucket in termsAgg.Buckets)
{
    // get the key
    var key = bucket.Key;

    // get the sum aggregation for this bucket
    var sumAgg = bucket.Sum("total");       
}
```

Take a look at the [docs on handling aggregation responses](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/writing-aggregations.html#handling-aggregate-response).

The JSON that you've posted looks like the result of serializing a `SearchResponse<T>` with another JSON serializer such as JSON.NET. This won't work as expected as

1. `SearchResponse<T>` has not been designed to be serialized again, only to be materialized by deserializing the Elasticsearch JSON response
2. If `SearchResponse<T>` is designed to be serialized again, it would likely not work with any other serializer other than the client's serializer because types may require specific serialization routines.

If you want to send the verbatim response from Elasticsearch back to the caller, there are a couple of options:

#### 1. Capture the response bytes with `DisableDirectStreaming()`, and send these to the caller

Either on per request basis

```cs
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool).DefaultIndex("gltrans");
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var searchResponse = client.Search<gltrans>(s => s
    .RequestConfiguration(r => r
        .DisableDirectStreaming()
    )
);
```

Or for all calls

```cs
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DefaultIndex("gltrans")
    .DisableDirectStreaming();
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
```

Then the response bytes are available on the response

```cs
var bytes = searchResponse.ApiCall.ResponseBodyInBytes;
var json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Not that this buffers request and response bytes in memory, so comes at a cost of higher memory usage and allocations.

#### **or**

#### 2. Use the low level client to make the call, returning a low level response

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var searchRequest = new SearchDescriptor<gltrans>()
    .Query(q => q.MatchAll());

var index = "gltrans";

var searchResponse = client.LowLevel.Search<BytesResponse>(
    index, 
    PostData.Serializable(searchRequest));

var bytes = searchResponse.Body;
```

You can use `client.RequestResponseSerializer` to turn the low level response into a high level response if you need to work with it

```cs
var bytes = searchResponse.Body;
SearchResponse<gltrans> response = null; 

using (var stream = client.ConnectionSettings.MemoryStreamFactory.Create(bytes))
{
    response = client.RequestResponseSerializer.Deserialize<SearchResponse<gltrans>>(stream);
}
```